# connecting two dedicated server with a v-switch

Tags: networking, virtual-network

Does it make sense to connect two servers in different locations with a layer-2 v-switch and then connect application and database with local IPs (e.g. 10.0.0.1)?

One server is the database, the other server is the application. Both servers are in the same country, but in different data centers.

Specifically, we are talking about hetzner root server and a hetzner v-switch. (https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/network/vswitch/)

My question ist:

Will this make the connection between those both server **faster** and/or more **secure** if I connect them with a v-switch?

Comment: What kind of vSwitch? How are you planning to create it?

Comment: thank you for askin @u1686_grawity. i improved the question and added more details.